# diff between small and larg files not running

Tags: diff

i am trying to compare beetwin 2 file and get output if they change
i am missing something

```
#!/bin/ksh
cd /tmp
FilesDiff=`diif -U 0 /tmp/file1 file2 |grep ^@ |wc -l`
countnew = `cat /tmp/file1 |wc -l`
countold = `cat /tmp/file2 |wc -l`
if $FilesDiff != 0 and countnew > countold
then 
    exit 0
else 
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have a spelling error, some parentheses missing around comparisions and some spacing errors. Fix them and the script will work:

```
#!/bin/ksh
cd /tmp
FilesDiff=`diff -U 0 /tmp/file1 file2 |grep ^@ |wc -l`
countnew=`cat /tmp/file1 |wc -l`
countold=`cat /tmp/file2 |wc -l`
if (($FilesDiff != 0)) && (($countnew > $countold))
then 
    exit 0
else 
    exit 1
fi
```